# SQLite function to specify exactly how the data is stored internally

Tags: sqlite, datatypes, size

I have used the `typeof()` function within SQLite before (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fcf0e/1), but I would like to go a little further this time.

I know that `INTEGER` can be stored internally as 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6 bytes.

**What I am wondering is if I can use a function to identify how the value is actually stored internally?**

I am looking for something more than just `INTEGER`, something like `INTEGER 4-byte` would be great or just `4-byte`

Answer (score 1):

The storage size has no effect at the SQL language level, so there is no SQL function to determine it.

However, the [record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format) is documented; SQLite always uses the smallest serial type into which the value fits.